# IOS image cannot be stretched

Tags: ios, uiimage

environment: 
Xcode4.3.1, sdk5.1

I want to stretch only part of the image, so i use write the code like this:

```
    leftImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"leftStyleBackground.png"];
UIEdgeInsets insets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(2, 14, 2, 2);
if ([leftImage respondsToSelector:@selector(resizableImageWithCapInsets:)])
    leftImage = [leftImage resizableImageWithCapInsets:insets];
else {
    leftImage = [leftImage stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:14 topCapHeight:2];
}
```

However,the result is this that the original image only appear repeatedly to fill the uiimageview frame.

If I use – stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:topCapHeight: method the image can be stretched correctly.

is any idea why the new method in ios5 cannot work?

Comment: Ever find a solution to this? I'm seeing the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

`resizableImageWithCapInsets`: tiles the image region.

If you need stretching:

For 6.0 and above - use: `resizableImageWithCapInsets:resizingMode`: with `resizingMode` set to `UIImageResizingModeStretch`.

Prior to 6.0 - use: `stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:topCapHeight:`